Grant the INHERIT PRIVILEGES privilege
I have database scheme her name NOUR ELKHUZAMA without underscore
I need to Grant the INHERIT PRIVILEGES to NOUR ELKHUZAMA
but I get an error:
Error starting at line : 3 in command -
GRANT INHERIT PRIVILEGES ON USER NOUR ELKHUZAMA TO PUBLIC
Error report -
ORA-00905: missing keyword
00905. 00000 -  "missing keyword"
What solution please?
I did try to Grant the INHERIT PRIVILEGES to NOUR ELKHUZAMA scheme to solve my main problem (Register scheme with ords)but I cant

Use a quoted identifier:
GRANT INHERIT PRIVILEGES ON USER "NOUR ELKHUZAMA" TO PUBLIC


Thank you guy, I did it that but now I have a problem that the classic case of transforming from CamelCase to Sumo_Wrestler_Case. Unfortunately, I can't directly rename a user schema in Oracle. my current scheme 'nour elkhuzama' I want to be 'nour'
I need Make a clone army of objects from the old schema and migrate them to the new, How I can export and import data through dump file

@Tayseer I love "Sumo_Wrestler_Case", but I think the conventional name for that style is Pascal_Snake_Case :)
